# Log deleted credentials from Windows Credentials Manager

Tags: windows-10, credentials-manager

For the past few weeks, my Windows 10 machine has decided to purge saved credentials from Credential Manager every day. This makes me having to constantly enter password in Outlook, OneDrive, iCloud, and git. Not all credentials are deleted, but certainly the ones for those services.

Is there any way to see a log of changes in Credential Manager so I can find the process deleting my credentials and stop it?

**Aug 16, 2020 Update:**
So it turns out that this is an issue coming from the Windows 10 2004 update released a few months ago.  Many users have reported similar problems (links below), but so far I have not been able to find a solution.

The issue seems to even affect website sessions, as all sites will log me out after restarting the browser, even with the "Remember me" option.

[Microsoft Answers - Systemwide password amnesia (v2004 build 19041.173)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/systemwide-password-amnesia-v2004-build-19041173/232381f8-e2c6-4e8a-b01c-712fceb0e39e?page=1)

Potential solutions still welcome.

Comment: I've been seeing similar behavior for the past week.

Comment: For backup see [How to Backup and Restore Windows Vault Passwords](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-backup-and-restore-windows-vault-passwords).

Comment: Look in in the Event Viewer at *Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows*. Open `Operational` under `CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-System`
and under `CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-User`. See if you can find some useful event message.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, but I got zero events in that location. Any other ideas?

Comment: I checked, and apparently there are no events this. Try perhaps as general troubleshooting with [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: [Windows 10 v2004 forgets stored credentials or passwords in Outlook, Edge, Chrome, etc](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-forgets-stored-credentials-passwords-outlook-apps/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by a bug in Windows 10 that clears saved credentials when running a task using S4U (checkbox in Task Scheduler for "Do not store password").

Disabling all scheduled tasks using S4U solves this issue.

Comment: I arrived to this answer following a link from user `w32sh`. Credit to this comment for the useful link.